# Move and zoom camera android maps v2 on Nexus7

Tags: android, google-maps, nexus-7

I've faced strange behaviour of Google Map v2 on my Nexus7 when trying to place camera in specified position.

Code:

```
public class PlacesFragment extends MapFragment {
    GoogleMap mapView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mapView = getMap();
        mapView.moveCamera(
           CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(50.4293817, 30.5316606)));
        mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}
```

This piece of code moves camera to specified position on Nexus4, but on Nexus7 2013 it moves camera to (19.1599396,30.5316606) position, which has right longitude, but not latitude.

I've found a workaround, but I'm still interested why this happens.

Comment: I'm guessing that google maps cancels first CameraUpdate when I try to perform second CameraUpdate.

Comment: What was the work around?

Comment: @user1163234 ugh, I don't remember. But I think the issue was that second call to moveCamera was canceling animation of the first call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have this problem this is the solution:

```
mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(50.4293817, 30.5316606), 11));
```